# How can I remove/hide modified information on DispForm.aspx for Append?

Tags: 2007, custom-form, site-column

I have a document library with a custom DispForm.aspx page.  In this library, I have a column with the option Append Changes to Text.  The DispForm.aspx displays the information correctly by this code

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="..." ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}"/>
```

Is there a way to have the DispForm.aspx page show the items, but not display the modified date and user who modified it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to use javascript/jQuery.  The code that you posted runs server side and you have no control over the output.  You'll have to do some front-end manipulation after the page has been rendered.  Hopefully, SharePoint gives you a good hook onto these elements, otherwise, it could be rather difficult.

Here's some jQuery to help you along:

```
// for the append-only comments, disable the click-to-view author and date
```

$("a[href*='_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=']").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("span").replaceWith($(this).html());
});
$("a[href*='/Lists/MyListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=']").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});